# Writing keypresses to SSD & wear leveling

Tags: ssd, filesystems, operating-systems, io

I am planning to write an application that tries to write as much to file as possible as to never lose any significant amount of data. It will write every key stroke including micro or even nano-second timing to the disk. Now this sounds like a lot, but it will take quite a bit of time still to reach a GB of data written. To alleviate things, I plan to write this data as updates to the end of the file using an output stream, but I will flush the stream immediately afterwards.

Now with SSD's, every time I write data it will usually write to a different location each time that an update is performed. I presume that the OS/FS just sends "sectors" to the drive, and that it won't be able to distinguish that they are just updates to the end of a file. So that would mean that even though the updates are small, that it will definitely peg the SSD wear leveling to no end.

Is the above description correct and should I consider a reasonable amount of buffering in the application? How much will modern filesystems cache themselves before writing to SSD? Or will buffering inside the SSD itself come to the rescue? Has anybody performed an analysis of such usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a situation like this, the OS should be buffering your writes and flushing them every few seconds or so. Also, most SSDs implement some limited form of write buffering that is "safe" so that it won't lose data in the event of power failure. Note that most storage devices and OSes operate in 4 KB blocks, so the system isn't going to be writing single bytes to the disk.

That said, if your application needs to continuously write small amounts of data to disk, it's best to explicitly use a write buffer, by either implementing one of your own or using an appropriate OS facility. Every disk write carries a nontrivial amount of overhead at the OS level, so you should be writing to a memory buffer that is flushed at an appropriate interval or when the buffer reaches a certain size (e.g. several tens or hundreds of KBs).

If you're writing reasonably-large chunks of data at regular intervals and not overwriting data in random places on the disk—and it seems like you're just writing a continuous stream of log data—you should not experience excessive write amplification or degraded performance. The drive's wear leveling will do just fine here.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer! With current machines I am just not worrying about OS overhead anymore. I didn't notice any when writing to RAM disk under Windows so I presume that's fine. Sure, it will be a high overhead compared to the key press, but I'm not going to cater for an infinite amount of monkeys.